# How to bind json data to custom class

Tags: c#, json

The below snippet is the Json response. I want to bind it to custom class.
Since i am new to json, Please some one suggest me how to achieve this.

```
{"status":"success",  
 "studentInfo":{"RegNo":"ABCD","ID":"123",
      "parentsDetails":[
   {"Parent_Name":"Anny","Gender":"M"},
   {"Parent_Name":"Danny","Gender":"F"}],
      "Student_Name":"Alex",
      "Student_Status":"Active"}
}
```

Comment: As a starting point. I'd suggest writing this structure out as a series of C# classes, and reading up on deserialisation.

Comment: I would suggest [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) to auto generate class from json.

Comment: The above link is throwing error. Can you post answer with an example.?

Comment: @CharanKumar what error, I'm able to generate the class.

Comment: Yeah..!! I got it.

Comment: Great thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to map the JSON properties into your custom class, maybe something similar to this:

```
public class Student
{
   public string status { get; set; }
   public string studentInfo { get; set; }
   //and so on...
}
```

Then, I suggest you use JSON.NET (Newtonsoft) to help you process the JSON data. The actual deserialization could look something like this:

```
Student myStudentData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Student>(yourInputJson);
```

`myStudentData` will give you access to all the JSON properties defined in your custom class. Also, please be aware that only the properties you define in your custom class will be mapped. For example, even if your JSON would contain something like an `errorCode` property, if you do not define it in your `Student` class, it will not be extracted. The other thing you should pay attention to is that if your input JSON does not contain one of the properties you define in your class, the deserialization will throw an exception. So for example if you input does not contain a `status` property, you'll get an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the class generated for your json object:

```
public class ParentsDetail
{
    public string Parent_Name { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}

public class StudentInfo
{
    public string RegNo { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public List<ParentsDetail> parentsDetails { get; set; }
    public string Student_Name { get; set; }
    public string Student_Status { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public StudentInfo studentInfo { get; set; }
}
```

And you can use it as

```
string json = @"{'status':'success', 'studentInfo':{'RegNo':'ABCD','ID':'123','parentsDetails':[{'Parent_Name':'Anny','Gender':'M'},{'Parent_Name':'Danny','Gender':'F'}],'Student_Name':'Alex','Student_Status':'Active'} }"
RootObject jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. This is half of what is required to answer the question. If you wish to fully answer, expand on how to deserialize into this class. It is also not a great idea to just provide code to someone without them at least demonstrating that they have tried something themselves. Better to point people to places they can learn themselves.

Comment: As per @DavidWatts answers.